# Kentico URL Redirection target options

Tags: kentico

Is there a way to force a new window for this menu action? I can't see anything. i was thinking of adding a class, and some JS code to redirect if the class is there.

Comment: If you want to have full control over HTML why not use Universal viewer to generate the menu instead of CSS list menu? :)

Comment: I've never used the Universal Viewer. I'm still learning Kentico and figuring things out as i go.

Comment: In that case check that out - https://docs.kentico.com/display/K9/Using+hierarchical+transformations It's really easy to use and you get full control over how your menu is generated (just like you do with standard repeater) so you don't have to "hack" the CSS list menu in some way. From my experience many people eventually switch to Universal viewer anyway because they stumble on something which they simply cannot do with CSS list menu.

Comment: I'm reading it now. I had looked at it, hoping this build would have a big mega menu, but it ended up being very simple. Cheers!

Comment: Could you please elaborate your question better? Doesn't seem like in what context you are asking this?

Comment: @Enn, it doesn;t matter what control you use to generate the menu, because there isn't any option in Navigation settings to open a URL in a new window. For example, I have 5 elements (the same page type) in the menu, and only one must be opened in a new window. It's not possible to achieve it without additional logic. And Mark asked the right question. It would be better if TreeNode had the option for it.

Comment: It matters.. a lot. The navigation settings you set for each separate page is used ONLY if you use CSS list menu to generate the menu and you have NO control over how the HTML of the CSS list menu looks like. If you want to have something more specific, you simply have to use repeaters, universal viewers or something else. Then when you defining transformation it is up to you to do the "logic". Its true that the option could be there, but I don't feel it is necessary as you can do the same thing by creating custom fields and then using these fields in the transformation.

Answer (score 1):

If your only intent is to open a window in a new tab, then why don't you set the target="_blank" in your transformation or where ever you are generating the HTML markup?
 I am not saying that it's incorrect, however it's just that you can avoid js for this and rather do it in HTML.

Comment: I'm just using a standard CSS list webpart for the small nav here. It was all built and working when someone wanted a new link to a LMS site.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what i've done.

In the Navigation panel, i added the class 'nw'. I have this snippet add the target attribute.

```html
  // we need to use .nw as a class to indicate that a link should open in a new window.
  $('.nw a, a.nw').each(function(i,v){
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.attr('target','_blank');
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the JS option and put in JS like: `window.open("http://www.google.com");`

Comment: I thought about that, but want to avoid any conflict with a pop up blocker. I think my solution will work. I don't see a need for this too often on this build.